# Android broadcast receiver to scan every incoming SMS for specific Contant

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I want to Scan every incoming SMS for specific content.
when specific content found then a specific task is performed.
suppose specific content string is "Hello world" when service find this string it will trigger a specific task i.e. take a photo with front camera and place that photo on a specific folder.
receiver have to run always when phone is on.

Comment: U need a broadcast receiver for that not a service

Comment: I doubt the users would want to have their SMS scanned.

Comment: I am getting a specific GPS msg from my old company's client, To avoid this I create an application which works same as. Whenever I receives a msg containing a specific word, my application simply removes is from the inbox and write the content into a file for backup purpose.

Comment: Please show us, what you have got so far.

Answer (score 0):

Create A SMS broadcast receiver for this that gets triggered when an sms is received

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

                if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        }
                        if (messages.length > -1) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
    }
```

Inside the receiver, you can check for the text you received and perform the particular action.

declare it in manifest also,

```
 <receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Also declare the permissions,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Nice example but for what purpose you required `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` here ?

Comment: Sahil, I doubt that your code will not work on Android 3.0 and above if you do not have any activity in your application.

Comment: I have tested it for gingerbread, but I'm not sure about Android 3.0. I dont think that a broadcast receiver is dependent on any activity.

Comment: Got it. So an activity should be used to start the receiver in case of Android 3.0 or above. I'm not sure whether the OP really wants to use an activity or not. Still a translucent activity could be a good option.